# Calculate mathematical operation using javascript eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why eval() does not evaluate expression like eval(2/2(2))

Comment: When people say "validate", you don't normally figure `replace` would be involved. "validate" means "figure out if it's okay or not", not fix the original contents into something more conformant.

Comment: `88*-+4` isn't authentic enough by my knowledge of math... _Some_ calculator you are building, it seems!

Comment: @AvinashRaj Unmatching string I have already given as eg. The mathching string will be normal mathamatical form to evaluate numbers using operators like +,-,/,*,(,),{,}.[.]

Comment: Validating operators are ok.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: 88*-+4 is unmatching string. :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tokenizer Regex I used for a simple calculator

```
(?:
    (?<number>\d+(?:[\.\,]\d+)?)|
    (?:\s+)|
    (?<operator><=|>=|<>|!=|\+|=|\(|\)|<|>|\*|.)|
    (?<other>.*)
)+
```

The named groups are not available in al languages  (<..>)

This is not a validator but a tokenizer though ;)